# limiting tangent line is parallel to asymptotic line

Tags: differential-geometry

For a (infinitely, if necessary) differentiable curve
$$ A(t) = (x(t), y(t)) $$
which diverges at $t_0 \in [-\infty,\infty] $, that is
$$ \lim_{t \to t_0 } | x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 |  =\infty $$ 
if there is a line $l: ax+by+c=0$ such that 
$$ \lim_{t \to t_0 } \frac{ |ax(t) +by(t)+ c | }{\sqrt{a^2+b^2} } = 0 $$
then this line $l$ is called the asymptotic line of curve $A(t)$ as $ t \to t_0$

I want to verify that the tangent vector of $A(t)$
$$A'(t) = (x'(t) , y' (t)) $$
tends to become parallel to line $l$ as $t \to t_0 $

It seems intuitively obvious and not difficult to prove at first glance but I have no idea how to approach..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems intuitively absolutely non obvious to prove your assertion.  Just disturb any curve that seem to fit your assertion by some $\sin(1/t)$-stuff.